# Jenkins build failed, artifactory issue

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins build and its failing with the below error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE or one of its
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE: Failure to find 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE in 
https://artifactory.abccompany.com:443/artifactory/java was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I have checked the socket Timeout for repository in the advanced tab, I changed it to 60 secs but still build is failing.

What could be the issue and how to have it resolved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some dependencies.

Locate the dependencies you're missing with `mvn dependency:tree`, then install them manually, and build your project offline once.